# how to draw samples with kernel-density-estimation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics

in a kernel density estimation the density of a arbitory point in space can be estimated by ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)):

[image: kde]

in sklearn it is possible to draw samples from this distribution:

```
kde = KernelDensity().fit(z)  # fit kde
z_sampled = kde.sample(100)   # draw 100 samples
```

is there an explicit formular to draw samples from such a distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the kernel.

But the general approach is simple. Let's assume a **gaussian-kernel** here:

- Chose one original point `x` uniformly from `X`
- Draw a value from the kernel linked to this point:

  - Gaussian: `sample = Gaussian/Normal(x, b)` (`x=mean; b=standard deviation`) where `x = uniformly chosen point` and `b=Bandwidth`.

Yes, there is no fitting-needed for sampling. Everything just depends on the original data and the *bandwith* parameter!

Compare with [sklearn's implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/neighbors/kde.py#L177):

```
i = rng.randint(data.shape[0], size=n_samples)

if self.kernel == 'gaussian':
    return np.atleast_2d(rng.normal(data[i], self.bandwidth))
```

where i omitted the underlying tree-structure needed for accessing `data[i]`. `np.atleast_2d` is just there to be compatible to sklearn's API.